# Maximising the P-Value in the shapiro Test

Tags: r

I am currently working on maximizing the P-value of a dependent interval-variable in the shapiro.test.
I have tried for several days, but nothing seems to work.
My problem is that I was advised to use a log(x) but this doesn`t yield any results, as R only gives out NA as an answer.

Are there any smart mathematical operations I can employ to maximise my P-value, as right now it is very small.

Thank you in advance

> abh_varb
>       [1] 1 3 3 0 1 0 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 2 0 1 0 2 2 1 3 2 0 1 1 1 2 2 0 1 1 0 1 3 2 
>       2
>       [37] 1 2 0 2 2 0 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 0 2 1 1 2 2 3 1 3 1 2 3 4 1 1 1 2 1 0 2 1 1 
>       3
>       [73] 4 1 1 1 1 3 0 2 0 2 3 0 2 0 1 2 2 2 4 2 3 2 1 3

```
            Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  abh_varb
W = 0.90306, p-value = 2.973e-06
```

With log(x) function:

```
 > shapiro.test(log(abh_varb))

Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  log(abh_varb)
W = NaN, p-value = NA
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add some sample code showing what you have tried

Comment: helpful to see your data too, or at least a summary of it. Torn on whether to vote to close as "unclear what you're asking" (i.e., not enough detail) or "belongs on CrossValidated" ...